# Is there a way to prevent iOS 7 from changing the colors of wallpaper images?

Tags: color, ios, screen-lock

When I create a custom wallpaper image and assign it to the lock screen on iOS 7, the colors of the image are changed. Oddly, if I take a screen capture of the lock screen, the colors match those of the original image.

Is there a way to prevent this? Is it intentional? Perhaps there's something subtle about color management on iOS that I'm missing.

---

Note: Providing images that document this is (clearly) tricky, but I hope to have some soon. In the meantime, perhaps this is a known issue or feature that someone can help with.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the "parallax" feature? To turn it off, go into Settings > General > Accessibility > Reduce Motion (turn it on)

Comment: Good thought; but no.

Comment: Maybe the lock screen can only properly display web-safe colors. Are your colors web-safe?

Answer (score 1):

There is a toggle you can flip to increase this effect even further.

Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Increase Contrast

I'm a bit surprised the screen capture restores the original color, but I'm not surprised that on iOS devices with a powerful GPU that processing is happening on something as layered as the home screen / springboard view. That processing is one of the main design features of iOS 7 as I see it. Increasing text legibility on the home screen and the lock screen are clearly design considerations I would expect to see - even if they are subtle or slight as you describe for your current choice of custom image.

Comment: I haven't quantified the effect, but what I'm seeing could, as you suggest, be some kind of contrast enhancement; the effect is diminished in dimmer ambient lighting. The result however is certainly *not* to provide much legibility (that would require a different typeface).